# Does a definite description such as "the train" or "the student" always signal uniqueness of the referent?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, natural-language

Some authors claims that a definite description such as  "the king" does not necessarily signal uniqueness. Examples given:

> (1) I’ve got this data from the student of a linguist. — Poesio (1994)
>
> (2) Jacqueline took the train from Paris to Moscow. — Carlson et al. (2005)

They would say that (1) does not require the linguist to only have one student, and that (2) would be appropriate if Jacqueline in fact has to transfer to get to Moscow, in which case she would take two trains, not one.

I am not a native speaker of English so I might be wrong, but these counterexamples and explanations seem wrong to me.

My question is: Is there any compelling argument either way?

Comment: Correct: obviously not. If we say "the train is a modern invention" we are not referring to a specific individual

Comment: There are plenty of examples like these. Another is "William is the son of King Charles." "The whale is a mammal." There are also context-sensitive uses of 'the' e.g. if I look out my window and observe, "The lawn needs mowing." Examples like these formed the basis of Strawson's criticism in his paper "On Referring".

Comment: On [Russell's conception](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions/#RusTheDes), definite descriptions do signal uniqueness, along with existence. Whether English nouns with the definite article follow Russell's conception is a different question. They trivially do not in many cases, but some of that that could be attributed to pragmatic/poetic deviations from literal meaning (as in using "the X" as an exalted plural reference). However, many authors argued that the mismatch is deeper, and "the" has the same literal meaning as "a" with only pragmatic/contextual difference.

Comment: (1) Doesn't sound convincing, sure he could have more, but the sentence implies you know one of them in particular that "the" refers to. (2) can be read in 2 ways, either as she took "the train" in the sense of a mode of transportation or in the sense of "the train from Paris to Moscow" so one specific train. Even if she changed trains mid journey the one from P to M would still be the uniquely identified. But as the others have mentioned "the X in general" referring to a concept or group might be a better example.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "*the train is a modern invention" we are not referring to a specific individual*" Yes we are. Everything in the sentence says we are. Not any actual train, though. Something else, the train as a mode of transportation.

Comment: @Bumble "*William is the son of King Charles*" Here "the son" refers to William, a unique individual. 2. "The whale is a mammal." "The whale" refers to a particular species. 3. "*There are also context-sensitive uses of 'the' *" Most uses seem context sensitive. We know who is referred to by "William is the son of King Charles" because we know who king Charles is. This does not change the fact that one individual is referred to.

Comment: @haxor789 "*but the sentence implies you know one of them in particular that "the" refers to*". We don't know the student in the sentence "**He got the book from the student of a linguist**". 2. "*"the X in general" referring to a concept or group*" Well, if it is ***referring to a concept or group***, then the referent is unique.

Comment: William is not the only son of King Charles. He is a unique individual but not a unique son. But in English we usually say, "the son" not "a son".

Comment: @Bumble "*English we usually say, "the son" not "a son"*" Yes, same as in French. There must be a reason, don't you think? If we are only interested in William, and here we are, the fact that there are other sons becomes irrelevant, so William is definitely the son of king Charles. To say "William, a son of king Charles" is more informative, but usually unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'the' in everyday English is usually used to refer to a specific instance, but it can also be used to refer to generalities, as the following examples show:

'I don't have the time to refine this answer as much as I would like'.

'The weather is very variable in England.'

'The price of food is at an all time high.'

'The only way is up.'

'The French dislike the English.'

'The mass of the electron is difficult to measure.'

'The rabbit always outruns the fox'.

'The rose is a beautiful plant'.

'The elephant never forgets.'

'Have you tried the food at Petra's restaurant?'

'The temperature overnight was unusually low.'

Comment: I don't see any of your examples as convincing. For example, ***The weather is very variable in England*** refers unambiguously to the type of weather predominant in England.

Comment: @Speakpigeon in what way are you unconvinced? I gave the examples to illustrate my statement that the word 'the' can refer to generalities. Try 'I prefer the violin to the tuba', and compare it with 'the violin on my desk'. The first phrase, which refers to violins in general, is more general than the second, which is refering to a specific violin.

Comment: '*I prefer the violin to the tuba*' Refers to a particular thing, namely a type of instrument, not to all violins, and nobody is going to mistake the violin in question for any actual violin.

Comment: I agree with you! I am simply saying that the idea of a type of instrument is more general than a reference to a specific instance of that instrument.